# Why isn't useState() hook working as expected?

Tags: reactjs, input, use-state

The below code isn't executing as expected. The email is set as the first character in the email input and the rest is set as password. And after that the alert in signIn function showing blank. I don't know why.Could somebody explain me and give me a working solution ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Auth = () => {
  const signIn = () => {
    alert(email + password)
  }

  const step2 = {
    stepCount: "Step 02/02",
    title: "Enter password",
    helperText: "If you have an account, enter your set password or if you dont't have an account enter a strong password for your acccount.",
    inputType: "password",
    onclickBtnText: "Proceed",
    onclick: (() => {
      setPassword(password)
      signIn()
    })
  }
  const step1 = {
    stepCount: "Step 01/02",
    title: "Enter email",
    helperText: "Enter your email to sign in to your account. Or if you don't have an account no worries! .We will create an account for ya !",
    inputType: "email",
    onclickBtnText: "Next",
    onclick: (() => {
      setEmail(email)
      setStep(step2)
    })
  }
  
  const [step, setStep] = useState(step1)
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const setInput = () => {
    step === step1 ?
      setEmail(email) : setPassword(password)
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexFlow: "column", alignItems: "center", }}>
          <h4 style={{ marginTop: "20px", marginBottom: "10px", color: "#a3a3a3", }}>
            {step.stepCount}
          </h4>
          <h2 style={{ marginBottom: "35px" }}>
            {step.title}
          </h2>
          <h4 style={{ marginBottom: "50px", color: "#b2b2b2", fontWeight: "500", }}>
            {step.helperText}
          </h4>
            <input type={step.inputType} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} style={{marginBottom: "35px"}} />
          <button onclick={step.onclick}>{step.onclickBtnText}</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Use of setInput looks very strange. In the `onChange` you pass in the element value but do nothing with it in the actual function

Comment: Oh! I forgot to add it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Slightly Refactored...

Your idea is elegant in that you are trying to reuse steps. There are gotchas with React hooks where it appears simple but there are closures going on under the hood plus some state update issues and little typos you had that made things slightly not work.

Here's a revised version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-forest-6vp9i?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

// this is your "Auth"
export default () => {
  // needed for state change/response on UI
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const signIn = () => {
    alert(step1.value + " " + step2.value);
  };

  const step2 = useRef({
    stepCount: "Step 02/02",
    title: "Enter password",
    helperText:
      "If you have an account, enter your set password or if you dont't have an account enter a strong password for your acccount.",
    inputType: "password",
    onClickBtnText: "Proceed",
    value: "",
    onChange: (val) => {
      step2.value = val;
      setValue(val);
    },
    onClick: () => {
      signIn();
    }
  }).current;

  const step1 = useRef({
    stepCount: "Step 01/02",
    title: "Enter email",
    helperText:
      "Enter your email to sign in to your account. Or if you don't have an account no worries! .We will create an account for ya !",
    inputType: "email",
    onClickBtnText: "Next",
    value: "",
    onChange: (val) => {
      step1.value = val;
      setValue(val);
    },
    onClick: () => {
      setValue(step2.value);
      setStep(step2);
    }
  }).current;

  const [step, setStep] = useState(step1);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexFlow: "column", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <h4 style={{ marginTop: "20px", marginBottom: "10px", color: "#a3a3a3" }}>
        {step.stepCount}
      </h4>
      <h2 style={{ marginBottom: "35px" }}>{step.title}</h2>
      <h4 style={{ marginBottom: "50px", color: "#b2b2b2", fontWeight: "500" }}>
        {step.helperText}
      </h4>
      <input
        value={value}
        type={step.inputType}
        onChange={(e) => step.onChange(e.target.value)}
        style={{ marginBottom: "35px" }}
      />
      <button onClick={step.onClick}>{step.onClickBtnText}</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I kept your clean idea but just extracted the bits out needed for state management to refresh properly. **Bonus**: you can keep your values encapsulated as well.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much... I appreciate your generosity. Could you explain me a li'l bit more of what you just did with useRef hook

Comment: @RonBis since you are using a "value" for each step, you'll want to persist it across renders. Using `useRef` allows you to save a reference pointer to persist objects across renders. You can then extract your steps if you have many more in other files in your design. I like it.